# iphone : how to stop shutter animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having 2 issues.

1) I want to know how can I stop animation of shutter when camera is loaded ? I am using UIImagePickerController. I have referred many answer from stack overflow but did not get succeed.

2) I have a custom button in camera using `cameraOverlayView` and want to open the photo library on click. I have code like :

```
- (void) showLibrabryPicker
{
    pickerLibrary = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerLibrary.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    pickerLibrary.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:pickerLibrary animated:YES];
    [pickerLibrary release];
}
```

it gets called when camera is already shown.

Thnaks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `UIImagePickerController`, there's nothing you can do about that initial shutter animation. It's actually there to hide the startup time. You can switch to using the AVFoundation and getting an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, which has no shutter animation, but you still get a latency between asking for the feed to start and it starting. I'm no hardware expert but I assume the delay is because the power management unit normally has that whole subsystem powered down.

Your code for `showLibraryPicker` looks more or less correct, though you may be calling `presentModalViewController:animated:` on the wrong actor. `UIImagePickerController` is a view controller, so if you haven't subclassed that (ie, the code you're writing is not itself part of the thing you have acting as a `UIImagePickerController`) then you'll want to do `[pickerController presentModalViewController:...]`.