# How to disable/Hide the UIImagePickerController Camera shutter in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, shutter

I searched lot in google and tried my level best but, still i cant fix this issue. I want to disable or hide the `UIImagePickerController` Camera shutter when it is opening. 
I searched in google and got advice to use `AVCaptureSession`. But, in my app i used `CustomOverlayView` in `UIImagePickerController` Camera with some buttons. In this case i want to disable or stop to show the Apple's Camera shutter. Simply the user won't to see the camera shutter when they pick the Camera `UIImagePickerController`. How can i do this? Can you please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098236/iphone-how-to-stop-shutter-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen some apps cover it up with their overlay, but you can't remove it.  AVCaptureSession really does sound more appropriate for your purposes.  I see one example here:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273